# Check login and redirect in Codeigniter not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a problem when use **check_login** function.
When I enter http://localhost/shopping/admin/login and put admin username and password, it does not redirect to **home admin page**. But when I try to
http://localhost/shopping/admin. It still redirect to **login page**.

```
/**
 * MY_Controller constructor.
 */
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public $data = array();
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //  $this->load->library('session');

        $controller = $this->uri->segment(1);
        switch ($controller) {
            case 'admin': {
                $this->load->helper('admin');
                $this->_check_login();
                break;
            }
            default: {

            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Check login admin
     */
    function _check_login()
    {
        $controller = $this->uri->rsegment('1');
        $controller = strtolower($controller);
        $login = $this->session->userdata('login');
        //redirect to login if not logged in.
        if (!$login && $controller != 'login') {
            redirect(admin_url('login'));
        }
        //redirect to home if login successful.
        if ($login && $controller == 'login') {
            redirect(admin_url('home'));
        }
    }
}

/*
 * admin_helper
 */
function admin_url($url = '')
{
    return base_url('admin/'.$url);
}
```

But when I remove

```
//redirect to login if not logged in.
if (!$login && $controller != 'login') {
    redirect(admin_url('login'));
}
```

> After I login with my admin, it redirect to home page successful.
>
> Why is it not working?

```
 /*
  * Controller login
  */
class Login extends MY_Controller
{

    function index()
    {

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('form');

        if ($this->input->post()) {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('login', 'login', 'callback_check_login');
            if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
                $this->session->set_userdata('login', true);

                redirect(admin_url('home'));
            }
        }
        $this->load->view('admin/login/index');
    }

    /*
     * Kiem tra login
     * */
    function check_login()
    {
        /*
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        */
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $password = md5($password);

        $this->load->model('admin_model');
        $where = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
        if ($this->admin_model->check_exists($where)) {
            return TRUE;
        }
        $this->form_validation->set_message(__FUNCTION__, 'Login fail.');
        return FALSE;


    }
}
```

Comment: in this function where you are setting session when user hit login button ??

Comment: @SoravGarg sr , i edited !

Comment: where you edited i can`t find your changes

Comment: @SoravGarg I added my controller login.

Comment: @SoravGarg thanks so much, i fixed my login controller. it's work !

Comment: Good, please give your valuable up-vote....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below statement

```
if (!$login && $controller != 'login') {
            redirect(admin_url('login'));
  }
```

will always return true because $login will always be false as you have not set its value in set_userdata and $controller will always return admin as controller because u are using segment 1 as index. so you are redireting to login page.

*set session correcty and check only session value not controller value for checking whether user authenticated or not
if session value login not set to true redirect to loign else redirect to home page

Answer (score 1):

still i can not find where you are using session i mean for set session generally we used `$this->session->set_userdata('user_login_data');` i think it is missing in your code .

```
<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $adminId = $this->session->userdata('unique_id');
        if(empty($adminId)){
            $this->load->view('login');
        }else{
            redirect('home/dashboard');
        }
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = base64_decode($this->input->post('password'));
        $arr = array(
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => md5($password),
            'user_type' => 'admin'
            );
        $result = $this->common_model->getMultiple('panel_login',$arr);
        if(!empty($result )){
            $this->session->set_userdata('unique_id',$result[0]['s_no']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('username',$result[0]['username']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('password',$result[0]['password']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('type',$result[0]['user_type']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('status',$result[0]['status']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('user_activity',time()); 
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}

?>
```

for your help i also attached my demo code for user login i hope it will help you..